# How do I create objects from values in an array in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have an array consisting of a list of words, and a wordcount and ID for each word. Sort of like:

```
var array = [[word1, word2, word3],[3,5,7],[id1,id2,id3]]
```

Now I want to create an object for each word with the word as the name and the count and ID as values. So it would look like this:

```
var word1 = {count: 3, id: 'id1'}
```

How do I achieve this? 
I tried doing it using a for-loop as shown below, but it doesn't work. How could I set the name of each object from the values in the array?

```
for (var y=0; y < array[0].length; y++) {
        var array[0][y] = {count: array[1][y], id: array[2][y]};
    }
```

Comment: I would prefer you to use loadash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having individual objects you could add the words in one dict object like this:

```
var words = {};

for (var y=0; y < array[0].length; y++) {
    words[array[0][y]] = {count: array[1][y], id: array[2][y]};
}
```

And, you can access `word1` as following:

```
words['word1'] // {count: 1, id: id1} 

// if the word1 doesn't contain spaces, you could also use
words.word1 //  {count: 1, id: id1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the `array [0]` are the ordered keys, and `array[1]` are the count and `array[2]` are the ids then:

```
var array = [[word1, word2, word3],[3,5,7],[id1,id2,id3]];

var orderedKeysArray = array[0];
var orderedCountArray = array[1];
var orderedIdArray = array[2];

//maybe add some code here to check the arrays are the same length?

var object = {};

//add the keys to the object
for(var i = 0; i < orderedKeysArray.length; i++) {
  object[orderedKeys[i]] = {
    count: orderedCountArray[i],
    id: orderedIdArray[i]
  };
}
```

Then you can refer to the object for the vars like so:

```
object.word1;
object.word2;
object.word3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Loadash

```
var array = [['word1', 'word2', 'word3'],[3,5,7],['id1','id2','id3']]

var output = _.reduce(array[0], function (output, word, index) {
    output[word] = {count:array[1][index],id:array[2][index]};
  return output;
},{});
```